# What is the difference between sendAction and send?

Tags: ember.js

I have defined two custom objects, whereby the first one is extending Ember.TextField and the second one Ember.Select. When the appropriate action is trigger in Ember.TextField I do some processing and if a requirement is satisfied then I propagate the action to the underlying controller using `@sendAction("actionName")`.

However, when I try to do the same using Ember.Select I get the following Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendAction'
```

and have to use `@get("controller").send("actionName")` instead. My mentor reckons that this inconsistency leads to spaghetti code and I do agree with him. Why can't I call `@sendAction` from Ember.Select, which is a preferred way I've come to understand, in Ember?

What is the main difference between the two?

Answer (score 18):

`sendAction` should be used when inside a component.  It allows you to breach the confines of a component, if that action is defined when hooking up the component.  This helps keep maintain the isolation guaranteed by components, but still allows the component to send messages if you want to listen to it. https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/

```
{{my-component someInternalAction=someExternalAction}}
```

`send` should be used everywhere else.

`Ember.Select` and `Ember.TextField` are both components, hence you need to use `sendAction`

Comment: Could you please expand "send should be used everywhere else" just a little bit, it's late and the deadline was here :/

Comment: `send` should be used within `views` (deprecated in 2.0), `controllers` (mostly deprecated in 2.0), and `routes` (still good and strong in 2.0). `sendAction` in components.

Comment: @Kingpin2k great answer and thanks for taking into account the version of ember!

Comment: I'll add you should use `send` (and *not* sendAction) in a component if you want a component to trigger an action *on itself*. `sendAction` is for triggering actions "passed to" a component. You may want to do this if some common functionality is needed by both the template and as part of a more complex action; if the functionality is not needed in the template, you can skip `send` by just writing a function and calling it.